# Arch/Plasma - PolicyKit window not opening for Virtual Machine Manager;

Tags: arch-linux, kde, plasma5, virt-manager, polkit

I'm relatively new to linux and I have using Arch linux as the host for some virtual machines for some time now. I don't know what triggered it, but lately 90% of the times I boot and open the Virtual Machine Manager window, the PolicyKit window that used to pop up to authenticate me doesn't pop up, leaving the Virtual Manager window on "Connecting..." and never loading the VMs. Doesn't matter what I do, nothing seems to fix it, only rebooting and hoping I'm in the 10% this time.

Does anybody know why this happens and how to fix it?

I have no idea what info to share here that would be helpful to fix this so if you need any just ask me and I'll add to the post.

**versions:**

```
$ uname -srm
Linux 6.2.13-arch1-1-vfio x86_64

$ plasmashell --version
plasmashell 5.27.5

$ kf5-config --version
Qt: 5.15.9
KDE Frameworks: 5.106.0
kf5-config: 1.0

$ virt-manager --version
4.1.0

$ pacman -Q polkit-kde-agent
polkit-kde-agent 5.27.5-1
```

**EDIT #1:**

```
● polkit.service - Authorization Manager
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/polkit.service; static)
    Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-06-14 13:15:14 -03; 2h 44min ago
    Docs: man:polkit(8)
Main PID: 1593 (polkitd)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 38244)
    Memory: 6.1M
        CPU: 348ms
    CGroup: /system.slice/polkit.service
            └─1593 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug

Jun 14 13:15:14 archlinux systemd[1]: Starting Authorization Manager...
Jun 14 13:15:14 archlinux polkitd[1593]: Started polkitd version 122
Jun 14 13:15:14 archlinux polkitd[1593]: Loading rules from directory /etc/polkit-1/rules.d
Jun 14 13:15:14 archlinux polkitd[1593]: Loading rules from directory /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d
Jun 14 13:15:14 archlinux polkitd[1593]: Finished loading, compiling and executing 7 rules
Jun 14 13:15:14 archlinux systemd[1]: Started Authorization Manager.
Jun 14 13:15:14 archlinux polkitd[1593]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 on the system bus
Jun 14 13:15:17 archlinux polkitd[1593]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:4 (system bus name :1.41 [/usr/lib/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/kde/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale C.UTF-8)
```

On the `polkit.service` logs, there is an extra log on successful (10%ers) sessions, right after the "Registered Authentication Agent" log:

```
Jun 14 12:59:43 archlinux polkitd[1157]: Operator of unix-session:2 successfully authenticated as unix-user:MYUSER to gain TEMPORARY authorization for action org.libvirt.unix.manage for unix-process:2010:18511 [/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/virt-manager] (owned by unix-user:MYUSER)
```

Comment: Has the PolicyKit daemon started successfully? Anything about this problem in its logs?

Comment: @HaukeLaging I guess so... the service `polkit.service` is running (check EDIT #1)

Comment: Can you check with any other application (e.g. mounting a partition) whether `polkitd` with your current settings logs all accesses? If it does and `virt-manager` does not appear in the logs then this may not be a PolicyKit problem but a `virt-manager` problem. You could start it in a console and run it through `strace` in order to (maybe) see what is happening: `strace -f -tt -o /path/to/virt-manager.strace virt-manager` Of course, this will slow down `virt-manager` a lot.

Comment: Yes I just had polkit pop up for accessing a pendrive, so it seems to be working. I'll try to run through strace.

Comment: As you don't get the pop-up for `virt-manager` this information is not much help. I intentionally asked whether it appears in the daemon logs, too.

Comment: Ok so you dont need the strace log only the daemon? What can I do now?

Comment: @HaukeLaging I don't have the polkit daemon (polkitd) installed.

Comment: Checking the `polkitd` logs is much easier than going through `strace` hell. If the access is in the logs then there is no need for `strace`. What do you mean by "I don't have the polkit daemon (polkitd) installed."? You have shown its Systemd logs... So I guess there is no log entry in the non-successful sessions (meaning it's `strace` time now...). Are the `polkit` log until then the same?

Comment: @HaukeLaging Hey I found the solution... simply restarted the libvirtd service and it started working... I rebooted 3 times and always behaved as expected. Thanks for the help man, if you want you can create an answer with that solution and I'll mark as the answer.

Comment: Maybe there is a race condition. Perhaps `libvirtd` usually started too early, before `polkit` was available. If you do not want to dig further into this I suggest you delete the question ("Problem went away on its own" is one of the deletion reasons) as in its current state it is not really going to help anyone else.

Comment: @HaukeLaging what about other people that run into this problem? Isnt it good to have a reference? Or maybe even when people start looking into this, isn't it good to find reports of what went wrong and how they fixed it?

Comment: @HaukeLaging Its not a matter of wanting to dig further but of having the knowledge to do so. I'm new to this but if you think I can help **you** with this, then by all means count me in.

Comment: Just to make sure I don't misunderstand you: Now it works after every reboot without you doing anything? Or does restarting `libvirtd` solve the problem every time? If the problem is just gone then I have no idea what might have happened. In that case I could turn the comments into my first community answer (trying to hide the fact that it would not be a real answer...)

Comment: Yeah, I dont have to restart libvirtd every time I boot. Just that one time. Weird right? Do the community answer, I'll be waiting.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I just rebooted again and I had to restart `libvirtd` again to make it work. This situation is not fully resolved.